# how can I train my model using python gensim

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to train my model and when I write these codes :

```py
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
```

and the error that I am getting is the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6ecb8a2d0ac7> in <module>

      2     model.train(tagged_data,

      3                 total_examples=model.corpus_count,

----> 4                 epochs=model.iter)


AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely copying some outdated example code. For example:

- recent versions of Gensim don't have an `.iter` property on the `Doc2Vec` model
- it's almost always a bad idea to be calling `train()` multiple times in your own `epochs` loop - especially as a beginner just trying to get things working

So: don't copy whatever source you're copying. It's not only out-of-date, it's suggesting something (the `train()` calls in a loop) that was never a great idea.

Instead, base your work on better examples, like the intro tutorial in the Gensim docs:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem, change model.iter to model.epochs. For example:

```
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    model.train(tagged_data,
            total_examples=model.corpus_count,
            epochs=model.epochs)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30974750)